# How to limit the search result in Magento 2 with query string

Tags: magento2, product-list, search, toolbar, querystring

How can I limit the search results in Magento 2 with query string,
we have something like this to perform the search

**http://domain.com/catalogsearch/result/?q=search_term**

Is there any query string parameter to limit the resulting rows?

ex : `?q=search_term&limit=5`

Answer (score 2):

You can use `product_list_limit` as the query parameter to restrict the results.

You can see that's how the toolbar class handles the limit:

```
public function getLimit()
{
    return $this->request->getParam(self::LIMIT_PARAM_NAME);
}
```

With:

```
/**
 * Products per page limit order cookie name
 */
const LIMIT_PARAM_NAME = 'product_list_limit';
```